# Extract audio from Transport Stream and preserve length

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg to extract audio from MPEG Transport Stream file recorded by DVB-S card. The command:

```
ffmpeg -i video.ts -vn audio.wav
```

The source file seems to be corrupted. I noticed the corruption happens from time to time, especially for videos longer than 1 hour. I've got errors like these:

```
[mp2 @ 0x1bb5500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:1
[mpegts @ 0x17eaf40] Continuity check failed for pid 5261 expected 2 got 6
```

The problem is that the resulting `audio.wav` is shorter than the source video (40m33s and 40m59s accordingly). **I'm looking for the way to preserve the original length in the resulting audio file.**

I tried the recent ffmpeg under Windows and avconv under Ubuntu, output format was MP3 and WAV. For every case I've got the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find whether it's possible to do it with ffmpeg however I found ProjectX -  a tool which tries to fix the broken TS stream. Website: http://project-x.sourceforge.net/

With:

```
java -jar ProjectX.jar -demux my_video.ts
```

the stream is demuxed into audio and video files which are guaranteed to have the same length. I simply mux them back using ffmpeg.